# When batch training a diffusion network, should we or should we not mix concepts?

Tags: diffusion-models, batch-learning

Let's say we are training stable diffusion 2, tenc and unet.

And we have two kinds of pictures in our dataset, apples and oranges.

And we are using a batch size of 2 or higher.

Should we put apples and oranges' pics together in one batch or should we separate them, ie only training 2 or more oranges together, then 2 or more apples.

What do you think?